# Getting all instantiated javascript objects and updating values

Tags: javascript, prototype

Here's a simplified example of an object I have.  What I would like to do is when I'm calling the update method, for it to update based on all objects.  So, I'll need to keep track of all  objects somehow (can I do this within this Game object? or do I need to wrap this?)

```
var Game = function() {
    this.data      = [];
}

Game.prototype = {

    add: function(game) {
        this.data.push(game);   
    },
    update: function(game) {
        for(i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            if(this.data[i].id == game.id) {
                this.data[i].name = game.name;
             }
         }
    },
    get: function() {
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}


var g1 = new Game;
g1.add({id: '5', name: 'firstname'});
g1.add({id: '6', name: 'secondname'});

var g2 = new Game;
g2.add({id: '5', name: 'firstname'});
g2.add({id: '6', name: 'secondname'});

g1.update({id: '5', name: 'firstname-updated'})

g1.get();
g2.get();
```

Basically, if you run this, you'll see that g1.get() writes the data with the updated id 5, where as g2, will still have it's original id 5 with name 'firstname'.

Thanks a lot for any help!

EDIT: Just wanted to add,  I would still want there to be multiple objects.  It's not always, that each object will have matching ids.  But if they do, they should all update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
function Game() {
  this.data = [];
}

// Object to store games with the same id
Game.games = {};

Game.prototype.add = function(game) {

  // Add the game to the existing array with same id
  if (Game.games[game.id]) {
    Game.games[game.id].push(game);

  // Or create new array if first with this id
  } else {
    Game.games[game.id] = [game];
  }
  // other stuff
}

// Update all games with same id
Game.prototype.update = function(game) {
  var games = Game.games[game.id]
  // games is a reference to an array of all the games with the same id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to following to get the desired result:

```
        var Game = function() {
            //this.data      = [];
        }

        Game.prototype = {

            data : [],

            add: function(game) {
                var found = false;
                for(i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
                    if(this.data[i].id == game.id) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                     }
                 }
                if( !found ) {
                    this.data.push(game);   
                }
            },
            update: function(game) {
                for(i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
                    if(this.data[i].id == game.id) {
                        this.data[i].name = game.name;
                     }
                 }
            },
            get: function() {
                console.log(this.data);
            }
        };
```